# Transform mesh to line up with empties, based on other child empties

Tags: transforms

This is a bit of a difficult one to explain, but I'll try my best. Essentially I have a mesh, generated by photogrammetry. I also have a 3D tracked camera exported from After Effects. Along with the 3D tracked camera from AE I also have some reference points I've put in the world in AE.

I need to line up the photogrammetry mesh so that the position, rotation and scale matches the original footage relative to the tracked camera. The only way I can think to do this is to put reference points on the tracked footage in AE (which get imported as empties in Blender), create empties at the same places on the photogrammetry mesh and then attempt to manually rotate, scale and position the mesh so that its child empties line up with the reference empties.

Here's a simulated picture for reference. On the left, the sphere represents my photogrammetry mesh with the empties added. On the right are the reference points added in AE:

[image]

And then when the process is complete, this is how it would look:

[image]

The problem is, doing this manually is extremely difficult and time-consuming. For one, the scale of both photogrammetry (using Meshroom) and AE's tracking is arbitrary, so the scales tend to be vastly different. It's also just straight up really hard to get everything lined up by hand.

So my question is this. Is there a way to do this automatically? Obviously the relative positions of the empties that I place by hand on the photogrammetry mesh, and the empties that come from the nulls I've added in After Effects won't be exactly the same, so any automatic solution would have to be a "best fit" sort of thing. But does this exist? Or is there perhaps a simpler way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to just learn how Blender's scripting works and wrote a script. I know there would be simpler ways to calculate the transformations but I'm no maths expert and I wanted to spend my time debugging my logic errors rather my maths errors.

Basically what this script does is take 3 input points (in the form of empties) relative to the photogrammetry mesh and 3 input points in the same position relative to the tracking data, then attempts to line them up with each other, bringing the photogrammetry mesh along with it. This actually works pretty well in my testing. It's obviously not the fastest workflow but it does work and that's the important part.

```python
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

#####################################
# TO USE:
#
# 1) create empties at three easily-identified positions in tracking data, called ea1, ea2 and ea3
# 2) create empties at the same three positions but in photogrammetry data, called eb1, eb2 and eb3
#    NOTE: eb1, eb2 and eb3 must be positioned IN THE SAME ORDER as ea1, ea2 and ea3!
# 3) name the photogrammetry mesh "photogrammetry"
# 4) run the script and be amazed
#
#####################################

# from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118783/41192
def createLookRotation(forward, up):
    rot = Matrix.Identity(3)
    rot[0] = up                 # x
    rot[1] = forward.cross(up)  # y
    rot[2] = forward            # z
    rot = rot.transposed()
    return rot.to_quaternion()

def doMeshThing(obj, mesh, empty1, empty2, empty3):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.verts.new(empty1.location)
    bm.verts.new(empty2.location)
    bm.verts.new(empty3.location)
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.faces.new([bm.verts[0], bm.verts[1], bm.verts[2]])
    bm.normal_update()
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    normal = bm.faces[0].normal
    guide = empty2.location - empty1.location
    quatRot = createLookRotation(normal, guide)
    obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    obj.rotation_quaternion = quatRot.inverted()
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
    obj.rotation_quaternion = quatRot
    bm.free()

ea1 = bpy.data.objects['ea1']
ea2 = bpy.data.objects['ea2']
ea3 = bpy.data.objects['ea3']
eb1 = bpy.data.objects['eb1']
eb2 = bpy.data.objects['eb2']
eb3 = bpy.data.objects['eb3']

mesha = bpy.data.meshes.new('mesha')
meshb = bpy.data.meshes.new('meshb')

obja = bpy.data.objects.new('obja', mesha)
objb = bpy.data.objects.new('objb', meshb)

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(obja)
scene.objects.link(objb)

doMeshThing(obja, mesha, ea1, ea2, ea3)
doMeshThing(objb, meshb, eb1, eb2, eb3)

bpy.context.scene.update()

# position and rotate objb (photogrammetry) to match position and rotation of obja (tracking)
photogrammetryMesh = bpy.data.objects['photogrammetry']
photogrammetryMesh.parent = objb
photogrammetryMesh.matrix_parent_inverse = objb.matrix_world.inverted()

objb.location = obja.location
objb.rotation_quaternion = obja.rotation_quaternion

# calculate average dimension difference here and scale
scaleDiffX = obja.dimensions.x / objb.dimensions.x
scaleDiffY = obja.dimensions.y / objb.dimensions.y
scaleDiffZ = obja.dimensions.z / objb.dimensions.z
#averageScaleDiff = (scaleDiffX + scaleDiffY + scaleDiffZ) / 3
averageScaleDiff = (scaleDiffX + scaleDiffY) / 2 # seems to be in local space, so z is useless
objb.scale.x = averageScaleDiff
objb.scale.y = averageScaleDiff
objb.scale.z = averageScaleDiff

bpy.context.scene.update()

parented_wm = photogrammetryMesh.matrix_world.copy()
photogrammetryMesh.parent = None
photogrammetryMesh.matrix_world = parented_wm

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
obja.select = True
bpy.ops.object.delete()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
objb.select = True
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```