# Change Pivot Point Rotation Relative to Flat Face

Tags: export, unity, origin, transform-orientation

I'm trying to export this Icosphere into Unity, but I want to have each poly be separate, with its own pivot point on its surface, and with the blue arrow on the manipulator widget facing out at 90 degrees from each poly, as if originating from the centre of the planet and passing through the poly. Currently every poly has the pivot point in the right place, but the orientation is wrong. How can I change this?

[image: Here you can see the pivot is in the right place, but is pointing 'up', not 'out'. All poly pivots are sadly pointing in the same direction.]

Comment: Hello :). There is a [very similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/118763/) that could help. With two solutions using a script.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :).