# Align Gizmo with local axes instead of global ones

Tags: 3d-manipulator, gizmo

[image]

As shown in the picture, even the cube is rotated, its Gizmo still aligns with global axes instead of local ones. Even when I have set Transformation Orientation to "local". Is it possible to display a local Gizmo?

**Edit:**

Strangely, when I choose "Move" or "Transform" tool, the Gizmo doesn't follow local axes.

[image]

But when I choose "Rotate" or "Scale" tool, without changing any other settings, the Gizmo looks right:

[image]

Now it seems like a bug to me. Or is there anything I missed?

Comment: Hello :). This could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170977/. Or if it's individual faces, then [this could help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170777/).

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank for your help. While I know I can transform along with local axes with G/S/R+XX/YY/ZZ, I would still like to make my Gizmo to reflect my Transformation Orientation setting. Is ti possible?

Comment: Sure :). When you rotate an object in *object mode*, the local orientation changes. Did you rotate it in object mode or in edit mode?

Comment: @JachymMichal It's object mode. I noticed some other weird behaviours, please take a look on my edit.

Comment: Oh :). This does indeed look like a bug. Including the thin gizmo lines and weird viewport visibility. It'd be great if you reported it through *Help > Report a bug*. Until it gets fixed, probably switching to 2.81 or 2.83 could help.