# Geometry Nodes / Python - Every face to rotate around one of its edge like a hinge

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Now that there are these nodes in Blender 3.4 Beta...

[image]

...is it possible to do this with Geometry Nodes or Python to happen automatically for all the faces?

[image]

[image]

Maybe with the help of this script, what I used to make those GIF-animations by hand (and used commotion add-on for offsetting the keyframes):

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177920/8282